# Apache AGE - How to use SKIP clause for efficient query results?

Tags: apache-age

I am working with Apache AGE and I am trying to retrieve a subset of my graph data using the SKIP clause. I have gone through the documentation and I understand that the SKIP clause defines from which record to start including the records in the output. However, I am not sure how to use it efficiently in my query.

I would like to skip the first three rows and retrieve only the last two rows from my graph. I have tried using the SKIP and LIMIT clauses together, but I am not getting the desired results.

How can I use the SKIP clause in Apache AGE to skip a specified number of rows in my graph data? I have tried a few different approaches, but I am not getting the expected results. Can someone provide me with some guidance on how to properly use the SKIP clause in Apache AGE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have six columns, and we want to retrieve different subsets  (2 columns) of them from the top, middle, and bottom at each instance.

**Top:**

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo', $$
  UNWIND [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] AS n
  RETURN n
  LIMIT 2
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

**Middle:**

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo', $$
  UNWIND [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] AS n
  RETURN n
  SKIP 2 
  LIMIT 2
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

**Bottom:**

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo', $$
  UNWIND [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] AS n
  RETURN n
  SKIP 4
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the answer Mohayu provided if you want to get the last two rows specifically you can use the `ORDER BY` close with `ASC` and then skip all the rows until 2 are left. For example

```
select * from cypher('test', $$ MATCH (a) 
RETURN a 
ORDER BY a ASC 
SKIP 2 $$) as (a agtype);
```

You can skip as many as you would like according to your graph to return only the last 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

The **SKIP** clause is useful when trying to obtain results after certain number of rows and it has many practical use cases. However, **LIMIT** clause is used in cases of acquiring only a limited number of results  no matter how large or small result set is.

For example if you are trying to find out students whose grade lies between 6th to 10th position then you can use effectively the **SKIP** and **LIMIT** clauses together like:

```
MATCH(n:student)
RETURN
ORDER BY n.studentGrade 
SKIP 5
LIMIT 5
```

Similarly you can customize the query for you case.

Answer (score 0):

The SKIP clause in Apache AGE is used to skip away a particular number of rows or records from a query's return set. You must take into account the following factors in order to effectively utilize the SKIP clause in your query to skip the first three rows and get only the final two rows from your graph:

1. Together with the LIMIT clause, the SKIP clause functions. The LIMIT clause defines the maximum number of rows to obtain right after skipping, whereas the SKIP clause determines the total number of rows to skip.
2. Your result set's record order is really important. You must make sure the records are arranged so you may skip the necessary number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Using SKIP requires you to know the exact number of rows you need to skip, because you can't use variables with the SKIP clause, if you don't know the exact number of rows then you need to consider another approach. You also need to consider edge cases of the data you really want to return, before thinking about how to use the SKIP clause, you want to return last 2 rows, and also skip the first 3 rows. Which is more of high importance? skipping the first 3 rows or making sure to return last 2 rows, what if there are just 2 records to return?, or 1? So let's assume you are making sure to always return just the last 2 rows then you need to construct your query in such a way that would be independent of the number of rows, if you don't want to order by anything specifically, just get the result in the order they were created. You can use this approach

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graph_name', $$
   MATCH (n:label)
   WITH n
   ORDER BY id(n) DESC   
   RETURN n
   LIMIT 2
$$) as (n agtype);
```

That returns the last 2 rows and if you have a specific property to order by then you can go ahead and use that instead of ordering by the `id`